# Matlab number of rows in excel file

Tags: excel, matlab, rows

is there a command of Matlab to get the number of the written rows in excel file?
firstly, I fill the first row. and then I want to add another rows in the excel file.
so this is my excel file:
[image]

I tried:

```
e = actxserver ('Excel.Application');
filename = fullfile(pwd,'example2.xlsx');
ewb = e.Workbooks.Open(filename);
esh = ewb.ActiveSheet;

sheetObj = e.Worksheets.get('Item', 'Sheet1');
num_rows = sheetObj.Range('A1').End('xlDown').Row
```

But num_rows = 1048576, instead of 1.
please help, thank you!

Comment: Is your file really empty? Sometimes you can create blank cells in excel and you cannot know for sure they aren't there. Create a new file and test the code with it to see what happens.

Comment: @Castilho
I tried what you suggested, but num_rows is still equal to 1048576. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file is empty, or contains data in only one row, then `.End('xlDown').Row;`  will move to the very bottom of the sheet (`1048576` is the number of rows in a Excel 2007+ sheet).

Test if cell `A2` is empty first, and return `0` if it is.

Or use `Up` from the bottom of the sheet

```
num_rows = sheetObj.Cells(sheetObj.Rows.Count, 1).End('xlUp').Row
```

Note: I'm not sure of the Matlab syntax, so this may need some adjusting

Comment: Only one row behaves the same as no data (try `Ctrl-Down` in excel to see how it works) See my edit

Answer (score 2):

You can use MATLAB's `xlsread` function to read in the spreadsheet.  This obtains the following fields:

```
[numbers strings misc] = xlsread('myfile.xlsx');
```

if you do a `size` check on `strings` or `misc`, this should give you the following:

```
[rows columns] = size(strings);
```

testing this, I got `rows = 1`, `columns = 10` (assuming nothing else was beyond 'A' in the spreadsheet).